# get element, caused change event in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, event-handling, onchange

i want to get know within `onchange` event handler, which control caused change (or blur) event.
i tried to use jQuery `$(":focus")` for that aim, but

```
$('.some_class').change(function (e) {
    console.log(e.target);
    console.log($(':focus').get(0)); // always `undefined`.
    /* ......... other code......... */
});
```

Comment: provide the entire event handler ...

Comment: $('.some_class').change(function (e) {
   console.log(e.target);
   console.log($(':focus').get(0));
   ......... other code.........
  });

Comment: @DotNetter please put the code in your answer

Answer (score 7):

```
$('.some_class').change(function (e) {
console.log(e.target);
console.log($(':focus').); // just remove the .get(0)
```

});
remove the .get(0),you can get the element which is on focus

Comment: and what i get? object jQuery is empty

Comment: if the element onblur, you can get the element onfocus

Comment: I cannot understand. Function `get` just returns object within jQuery collection. So, if collection is not empty, then calling `get(0)` allow me to obtain focused element. Then why do you suggest to remove it? Or maybe I'm mistaken somewhere?

Comment: because when you onblur the element , you not onfocus in any element on the next time.  get(0) is not unreasonable，because just on element on same time can onfocus

Answer (score 4):

In jQuery, `this` refers to the element with the event handler and  [`event.target`](http://api.jquery.com/event.target/), if `event` is the parameter to your event handler callback will be the source of the event, if, for example, you clicked on a child element and the click bubbled up.

The focus event gets fired after the blur event, so there will be a short period of time during which no element has focus.  If you really need this, you could set a short timeout to see if another `input` has focus a couple milliseconds after the original one gets blurred.

Comment: Yes, It 's so. But the problem is that `this` word points to my textbox but not to focused element. `Event` i use just to prevent it in some cases.